# сортировка большого файла

Tags: c++, c, сортировка, perl

задача: удалить дубли (строки) из текстового файла (1 - 4GB), OS: Windows 7 x64, ОЗУ: 8GB, Perl (v5.24.1).
вопрос: как ускорить процесс (желательно без подключения/установки модулей с cpan)
 при использовании скрипта ниже, на 1гб файл уходит в среднем 1,5 часа.

при попытке "загнать" весь файл в хеш (память), вываливается с ошибкой: "out of memory".
в целом, задача сводится к сортировке.
как видно, в скрипте использую алгоритм,
где в хеш добавляются строки которые начинаются с первого символа - таким образом задействуеться меньше памяти.

так же, возможен вариант сортировки по длине строки.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $time = localtime();

my $list = "1.txt";

my % sym;

open A, $list;
while(<A>){
    chomp;
    next unless $_;
    my $s = substr($_, 0, 1);
    $sym{$s}++;
}
close A;

for my $sym(sort keys % sym){
    #print "$sym\n";
    my %h = ();
    open A, $list;
    while(<A>){
        chomp;
        my $s = substr($_, 0, 1);
        if($s eq $sym){
            $h{$_}++;
        }
    }
    close A;

    open B, ">>clearlist.txt";
    for(sort keys %h){
        print B "$_\n";
    }
    close B;


}

print "$time\n", scalar localtime; <>;
```

доп: как я понимаю, для ускорения в perl нужно свести к минимуму число итераций, те если всего 94 символа то открытие и считывание файла будет происходить 94+1 раз, именно на считывание и уходит большинство времени. для С или С++ чтение файла будет происходить гораздо быстрее, если есть возможность привести пример кода - буду благодарен, сам давно не брал сей инструмент в руки - читайте комментарии ниже

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61644/discussion-on-question-by-usr13---).

Comment: Если нет необходимости сохранять исходный порядок строк в файле, то `cat file.txt |sort |uniq`. Виндовые порты этих программ имеются.

Answer (score 1):

Как бы я это делал:

1) Взять C++

2) Загрузить файл в память

3) Многопоточно найти начала строк, построив индекс (массив указателей на начала строк).

4) Отсортировать индекс.

5) Записать выходной файл, пробежав по созданному индексу.

Comment: с С++ не дружу, на С очень давно что-то писал, да и лень возиться с компиляцией, есть пример, готовых, скомпилированных программ? пробовал sort или uniq из UnxUtils или UnixUtils но все равно медленно

Comment: Готового примера, к сожалению, у меня нет. У вас данные в однобайтовой кодировке?

Comment: однобайтовой - не знаю) но можно сделать таковой, не думаю что многобайтовые будут нужны